find command does not work
I have file Info.plist in /Users/admin/dev/repos/SwiftAdExample/SwiftAdExample folder, but I can't find it from /Users/admin/dev/repos/SwiftAdExample:
admin@son SwiftAdExample % cd /Users/admin/dev/repos/SwiftAdExample/SwiftAdExample
admin@son SwiftAdExample % ll
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  5 admin  staff  160 Sep 25 01:02 Assets.xcassets
-rw-r--r--@ 1 admin  staff  399 Sep 25 01:02 ContentView.swift
-rw-r--r--@ 1 admin  staff  444 Sep 25 03:06 Info.plist
drwxr-xr-x  3 admin  staff   96 Sep 25 01:02 Preview Content
-rw-r--r--@ 1 admin  staff  248 Sep 25 01:02 SwiftAdExampleApp.swift
admin@son SwiftAdExample % find . -iname *.plist
./Info.plist
admin@son SwiftAdExample % cd ..
admin@son SwiftAdExample % find . -iname *.plist
zsh: no matches found: *.plist

how is it possible?

The error message gives a clue: It‘s zsh not being able to expand *.plist (for obvious reasons) which gets flagged as an error (bash would just pass *.plist to find if it can't expand it), find doesn‘t even run.
One way to solve this is
find . -iname '*.plist'

a more zsh-ish way would be to use ls -ld -- **/*.plist.
